# if condition in javascript not working

Tags: jquery

I have this code in JS:

```
if($('.log input:checked')) 
    {
        alert('login checked');
        alert('do what you want');
    }
    else 
    {
    alert('login not checked');
        alert('you can not do what you want');
}
```

But it is not working correctly. IS the IF ELSE condition wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( $('.log input').is(':checked') ) { // true/false
```

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is) in a jQuery fashion (it's descriptive) and will return a boolean against the matched element.
But you can also use the JS `.length` property.

**An even better solution** (kindly suggested by @macek)

```
if( $('.log input').prop('checked') ) { // true/false
```

Comment: Great, it is working, thanks a lot. After 7 minutes I will tick your answer ;), cause I have to wait.

Comment: jQuery has `.prop()` for this.

Comment: @macek after you left a comment actually realized "how could I miss that?!" :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although using `:checked` is the preferred way of testing if a radio button is checked you could also simply check if `$('.log input:checked')` has any length.

```
if($('.log input:checked').length) {
    alert('login checked');
} else {
    alert('login not checked');
}
```

This is completely different from your if condition because `length` will either return the number of checked elements (indicating TRUE) or 0 (zero) indicating FALSE.

In your example `if($('.log input:checked'))` will always result in a non-FALSE result which should bring up the `login checked` message no matter if the radio button is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually be using `.prop()` for this. It will return a `true|false` value.

```
if ( $('.log input').prop('checked') ) { ...
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

try this small plugin:

Plugin:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.eachChequed = function(fnc, fnnc) {

        var
            ck = $(this).filter('[type="checkbox"], [type="radio"]'),
            isFnc = $.isFunction(fnc),
            isFnnc = $.isFunction(fnnc);

        function callFnc(el) {
            if (isFnc) {
                return fnc.call(el);
            }
            return true
        }

        function callFnnc(el) {
            if (isFnnc) {
                return fnnc.call(el);
            }
            return true;
        }

        ck.each(function(i, el) {
            try {
                var r = $(el).is(':checked') ? callFnc(el) : callFnnc(el);
                return r;
            } catch (e) {}
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Run:

```
$('input').eachChequed(function(){

    console.log('checked', $(this));

},function(){

    console.log('no checked', $(this));

});
```

Test: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/ckaYB/)